# Google Chrome fires keydown event when form autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

On the following JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/mc38pbsy/6/

**HTML**

```
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="password" name="password">
```

**JS**

```
 $(document.body).on( "keydown", function (e)
 {
     console.log ('::: Keycode :::');
     console.log (e.keyCode);
     console.log (e.key);
     console.log (e.location);
     console.log (e.code);
 });
```

On Chrome, when you auto-fill the form, the keydown event fires twice, any idea why and how to prevent this behavior?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) mentions that this event will be fired during IME composition so I guess that is why it is triggered.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately, this is not Key up nether Down.

Comment: I suspect that since you are binding to `document.body` that the event is bubbling up beyond the scope of the input element. Would advise a less ambiguous selector or binding.

Comment: @Twisty, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
$(document.body).on("keydown", "input", function(e) {
  console.log('::: Keycode :::');
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  console.log(e.key);
  console.log(e.location);
  console.log(e.code);
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vnd5ez3f/2/

Tested and working in FireFox on Linux. Sorry, I do not have Chrome to test with.